# Java programs don't necessarily start from main(), do they?

Tags: java

My instructor used to tell me that Java programs start from the main function. However, is this true?

I mean, if there are any global variables declared, they get allocated memory before the main() begins, right?

Comment: FYI, there are also servlets, applets, etc. They all have different entry points.

Comment: Maybe applets' init() starts before main()(if it has any)

Comment: I don't know about servlets and applets.

Comment: @AlexShesterov Servlets and applets are not self-contained Java programs. The JVM that runs them *does* start from some `main` method somewhere.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik, true.

Comment: ... thought the `main` method of servlet container may still be considered too low-level for a Java web developer.

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is true that a Java program may be executed in entirety *before* the main method executes. Any program of the form

```
class X {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      ... any code as long as it doesn't refer to args ...
  }
}
```

can be rewritten to

```
class X {
  static {
      ... the same code ...
  }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  }
}
```

and have exactly the same behavior. Note that the `main` method is still required, but it will execute after all other code of the program.

Answer (score 2):

You can find more details about this in the documentation here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html

**Short version:**

1. JVM is started and attempts to call the main method
2. It finds out that the class is not loaded, so it tries to load the class
3. All the super-classes need to be loaded as well
4. Then it finds out that the class is not initialized so it initializes it (static variables are initialized here)
5. It starts executing the main method